# Why is "About trying to modify my system settings"?

Tags: security, settings

I got this popup completely out of nowhere:

[image]

At the time it happened, I was installing homebrew for the first time, in a zsh terminal window. This doesn't seem relevant but there isn't much more information I can give.

After I'd already closed the popup, I looked for open programs and windows and there was nothing called "About".

What is "About" and why did it suddenly want to modify my settings?

In general, how should I, as a user, find out the security/privacy implications of these kinds of request?

Comment: About is the System Settings > General > About settings page. Unclear why it's doing this though.

Comment: @Ezekiel I didn't have that settings screen open. This is a new mac, and I was installing homebrew for the first time when this popped up.

Comment: Could certainly be a misattribution, but the icon and name matches the settings page